# How to Re-dimension array in the given code below

Tags: excel, vba

I need to expand the array as per below.
Searched for answers but none seem to help as below code.

```
Sub MakeOneColumn()

Dim vaCells As Variant
Dim vOutput() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lRow As Long

If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    If Selection.Count > 1 Then
        If Selection.Count <= Selection.Parent.Rows.Count Then
            vaCells = Selection.Value

            ReDim vOutput(1 To UBound(vaCells, 1) * UBound(vaCells, 2), 1 To 1)

            For j = LBound(vaCells, 2) To UBound(vaCells, 2)
                For i = LBound(vaCells, 1) To UBound(vaCells, 1)
                    If Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0 Then
                        lRow = lRow + 1
                        vOutput(lRow, 1) = vaCells(i, j)
                    End If
                Next i
                lRow = lRow + 1
            Next j

            Selection.ClearContents
            Selection.Cells(1).Resize(lRow).Value = vOutput
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

The above code works without the added row "lRow = lRow + 1". However, I need a blank row for each column in the array. With the added row I get a runtime error 9, subscript out of range.

Comment: I tried running the code and it worked fine at my end. I am using excel 2007. Can you tell which version of excel you are using? Also will u provide the screenshot of your sheet so that i can simulate the issue.

Comment: @user2063626, I found that the code fails when there are values in all the cells in the selection. It's due to the double iteration of lrow.

Comment: +1 for using variables to loop instead of Ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly change your redim statement to below

```
  ReDim vOutput(1 To (UBound(vaCells, 1) * UBound(vaCells, 2)) + UBound(vaCells, 2), 1 To 1)
```

Comment: @user2081581 Please accept/vote if you are agree with solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are iterating lrow twice, once in the `i` loop and once in the `j` loop.  If you check, you should discover that the error only occurs when there are values in all the cells in the selection.

The fix is set the initial value of`lrow` outside of the j and i loops and then iterate *after* you make the assignment of the current cell's value to `vOutput`. It looks like this:

```
  lRow = 1
  For j = LBound(vaCells, 2) To UBound(vaCells, 2)
      For i = LBound(vaCells, 1) To UBound(vaCells, 1)
          If Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0 Then
              vOutput(lRow, 1) = vaCells(i, j)
              lRow = lRow + 1
          End If
      Next i
  Next j
```

In passing, I would note that you don't need the `TypeName` test because a selection is always of type Range.